# Calling Bash Commands With Multiple args From Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

I write this code in my rails project.It's to execute a shell script ,But my shell script can catch @directdown only.

rails script

```
@cmd = "/downafile.sh #{@directdown} #{@file.id} #{@filename}"
`#{@cmd}`
```

shell script

```
echo $1 >> /tmp/ceshi.tmp
echo $2 >> /tmp/ceshi.tmp
echo $3 >> /tmp/ceshi.tmp
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` and system command works in similar manner.
But system method will return true on success.

Try with this:

```
@cmd = "/downafile.sh '#{@directdown}' '#{@file.id}' '#{@filename}'"
  `#{@cmd}`
```

Comment: This is not safe -- consider the case where a filename is passed of `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` (and yes, literal quotes are allowed in UNIX filenames).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `puts @cmd` to see the command generated and see whether the command is what you intended. If it is try executing it from the terminal to test whether your shell script works. I think the parameters `@file.id` and `@filename` value may be `nil` so on interpolation it will be replaced by "". puts their values also to check.

Comment: hi,i can see whole args when i **puts @cmd**

Comment: @jean...try using that in the terminal..and see what happens?

Comment: it's solved.`@cmd = "/downafile.sh '#{@directdown}' '#{@file.id}' '#{@filename}'"`

Comment: @jean..it may be because the varible values may have spaces in between and part after space will be treated as another argument..so using '' in arguements will force it to take it correctly

Comment: @jean, that's not a safe solution against hostile names. A filename that contains a literal quote character could escape the quoting and run arbitrary shell commands.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is the meaning of `` in Ruby, but I think you can use the system function to invoke an external program. Something like,

```
   @cmd = "/downafile.sh #{@directdown} #{@file.id} #{@filename}"
   system(@cmd)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: system(@cmd) executes the command and gives true if the command was executed successfully and otherwise false. `` executes the command and returns its screen output. For example ` ls `  will give `"app\nconfig\ndb\ndoc\nlib\nlog\npublic\nRakefile\nREADME\nscript\ntest\ntmp\nvendor\n"` as output.

Comment: [6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)

Comment: `system()` use permits shell injection attacks -- consider a file named `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.txt` (yes, all those characters are allowed in filenames on Linux).